# apply custom function to a column of array type ofdataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a dataframe with a column named 'counts' and I would like to apply a custom function "do_something" to each of the elements of the column, meaning each array. I do not want to modify the dataframe, I just want to do a separate operation with the column counts. All arrays of the column have the same size.

```
+----------------------+---------------------------------------+
|id|              counts|
+----------------------+---------------------------------------+
|1|          [8.0, 2.0, 3.0|
|2|          [1.0, 6.0, 3.0|                
+----------------------+---------------------------------------+
```

When I am trying this:

```
df.select('counts').rdd.foreach(lambda x: do_something(x))
```

even if i try without lambda it gives the same error.

it fails on the line above with

> Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 df.select('counts').rdd.foreach(lambda x: do_something(x))
>
> /usr/hdp/2.5.3.0-37/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py in foreach(self, f)
>       745                 f(x)
>       746             return iter([])
>   --> 747         self.mapPartitions(processPartition).count()  # Force evaluation
>       748 
>       749     def foreachPartition(self, f):
>
> /usr/hdp/2.5.3.0-37/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py in count(self)    1002
>   3    1003         """
>   -> 1004         return self.mapPartitions(lambda i: [sum(1 for _ in i)]).sum()    1005     1006     def stats(self):
>
> /usr/hdp/2.5.3.0-37/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py in sum(self)
>       993         6.0
>       994         """
>   --> 995         return self.mapPartitions(lambda x: [sum(x)]).fold(0, operator.add)
>       996 
>       997     def count(self):
>
> /usr/hdp/2.5.3.0-37/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py in fold(self,
>   zeroValue, op)
>       867         # zeroValue provided to each partition is unique from the one provided
>       868         # to the final reduce call
>   --> 869         vals = self.mapPartitions(func).collect()
>       870         return reduce(op, vals, zeroValue)
>       871
>
> /usr/hdp/2.5.3.0-37/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py in collect(self)
>       769         """
>       770         with SCCallSiteSync(self.context) as css:
>   --> 771             port = self.ctx._jvm.PythonRDD.collectAndServe(self._jrdd.rdd())
>       772         return list(_load_from_socket(port, self._jrdd_deserializer))
>       773
>
> /usr/hdp/2.5.3.0-37/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py
>   in **call**(self, *args)
>       811         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
>       812         return_value = get_return_value(
>   --> 813             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
>       814 
>       815         for temp_arg in temp_args:
>
> /usr/hdp/2.5.3.0-37/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a,
>   **kw)
>        43     def deco(*a, **kw):
>        44         try:
>   ---> 45             return f(*a, **kw)
>        46         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
>        47             s = e.java_exception.toString()
>
> /usr/hdp/2.5.3.0-37/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py
>   in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
>       306                 raise Py4JJavaError(
>       307                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
>   --> 308                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
>       309             else:
>       310                 raise Py4JError(

although all input arrays have the same size.

```
big_list=[]
def do_something(i_array):
    outputs = custom_library(i_array) # takes as input an array and returns 3 new lists
    big_list.extend(outputs)
```

Comment: What operation you need to do on each array.?

Comment: Let's start with the error message: where does this error arise?
P.s. probably you won't need a lambda, just tossing `do_something` as argument would work. :)

Comment: @Uvar even if without lambda i get the same error

Comment: @Suresh I need to get each array of the column and use it with the function do_something to create a new list big_list

Comment: @Vas of course it does, nothing about the functionality changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `UDF` modifies a python object, that is :

- exterior to the dataframe, even if the function worked you wouldn't be able to access the value since you're not returning it to the rows of your dataframe
- huge, it will have at least three times as many elements as the number of rows in your dataframe

You can try doing this instead:

```py
def do_something(i_array):
    outputs = custom_library(i_array)
    return outputs

import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
do_something_udf = psf.udf(do_something, ArrayType(ArrayType(DoubleType()))
```

`DoubleType()` or whichever type you return

```py
df.withColumn("outputs", psf.explode(do_something_udf("count")))
```

You'll have three times as many rows as `df`

Comment: Instead of explode, we can index the wrappedArray returned from do_something_udf to form columns.So, by this, I think, each row will have inner list as separate columns and no changes in row counts.